# Can't deploy nativescript app to ios emulator or real device

Tags: nativescript

I have successfully deployed my nativescript app to my ios and android devices and emulators many, many times. But now, when I try to deploy the app to ios, the builder stops at `Project successfully prepared (ios)` and won't load it to the emulator or device.

I deleted the hooks, node_modules, and platforms folders, then rebuilt with the same result. I can successfully run the app if I run it directly through XCode, just not from the nativescript cli.

Here's the output from `tns doctor`

```
✔ Getting environment information 

No issues were detected.
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
✔ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
✔ The Android SDK is installed.
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Xcode is installed and is configured properly.
✔ xcodeproj is installed and is configured properly.
✔ CocoaPods are installed.
✔ CocoaPods update is not required.
✔ CocoaPods are configured properly.
✔ Your current CocoaPods version is newer than 1.0.0.
✔ Python installed and configured correctly.
✔ The Python 'six' package is found.
✔ Xcode version 11.6.0 satisfies minimum required version 10.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 6.7.8 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-core-modules has 6.5.12 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-android has 6.5.3 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-ios has 6.5.2 version and is up to date.
```

Any idea as to why I can deploy from XCode but not the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. In my situation, the nativescript-videorecorder plugin has a hook that runs during the after-prepare phase of the build process. The after-prepare script creates a promise that only resolves if it finds the AndroidManifest.xml in the platforms folder. When I delete the platforms folder to do a clean rebuild of ios, the AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist causing the promise to hang.

If I build for android first, the ios build runs fine and deploys to my simulator and real device.

I [notified the owner](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-videorecorder/issues/79#issuecomment-665255877) of nativescript-videorecorder. Hopefully this helps someone else who may have a similar problem with this or another plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems in the past, and it has always meant doing an update of Nativescript and then restarting my system. However, your tns doctor output looks basically the same as mine and I'm not having any issues with this.  Not sure what to say -- maybe try a new `npm install -g nativescript` -- but it looks like you are already up to date.  I've found in my experiences that this seems to happen if Xcode has updated and the version of Nativescript I have is one behind.  Your situation may be for a different reason.  Also, for whatever reason, I also found I need to completely reboot (paradoxical as that sounds) after doing an update to get things working again.  That led me to speculate at one point that something in the connectivity layer might get jiggered up and causing things to wait for a ready state that never appears (?) but that doesn't really make much sense either on deeper thought.  Wish I had a more definitive suggestion!

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. The command-line build process started working again, but I don't know why. Something is getting disconnected and I wish I knew what it was so I could quickly fix it and move on when it happens. Hopefully someone can share more insights to help us out.